# Send Bulk Email from Visualforce, how to get Salesforce default email compose with preview?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I understand that opening the Salesforce email compose popup directly from VisualForce is not possible and it is recommended to use the URL format '_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid=' instead.

However, I have a use case where I need to send bulk emails, and the Salesforce email compose functionality provides a preview with an edit option. I require this preview with edit functionality for my use case, along with the ability to send bulk emails.

I have searched for a solution to utilize the existing Email Compose UI from VisualForce, but haven't found any suitable approach.

I kindly request your assistance in finding the right solution for this requirement. Thank you!